# xpath xsl concat

Tags: xslt, xpath

given the following

```
<ZIP0>10015</ZIP0>
<ZIP1>10016</ZIP1>
...
<ZIP99>10016</ZIP99>
```

im using xpath concat() in order to combine the element name and integer:

```
<ZIP><xsl:value-of select="concat('ZIP','0')"/></ZIP>
```

concat returns the literal string...

```
<ZIP>ZIP0</ZIP>
```

of course, what is intented is,

```
<ZIP>10015</ZIP>
```

how to evaluate the string expression returned from concat.

and this also offers the same result:

```
<xsl:variable name="tmp" select="concat('ZIP','0')"/>
<ZIP><xsl:value-of select="$tmp"/></ZIP>
```

in fact, its evaluated like,

```
<xsl:value-of select="'ZIP0'"/>
```

opposed to

```
<xsl:value-of select="ZIP0"/>
```

cheers

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide an actual, complete and well-formed XML document. Without this, any specific XPath expression provided in an answer may not select the wanted nodes in the document that we haven't been shown. -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
<ZIP><xsl:value-of select="*[name() = concat('ZIP','1')]"/></ZIP>
```

Long answer - in an expression like the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ZIP1"/>
```

`ZIP1` is actually shorthand for `child::ZIP1` which means (roughly) look for a child element with a name matching ZIP1.  The text `ZIP1` is called a name test.  Unfortunately there is no way to build a name test dynamically from strings.  You have to either specify the name exactly or use a wildcard `*`.

Since we don't know the exact name, we have no choice but to use the wildcard `*` followed by a predicate expression which filters out the nodes we are not interested in.  The predicate will be invoked on every node in our list.  The `name()` method will return the tag name of the node being tested, so all we have to do is ensure that the name equals the string that we want.

For reference see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath

Comment: thanks
unfortunately doesnt work as expected. neither does the following

`<ZIP><xsl:value-of select="*[matches(name(), concat('ZIP','1'))]"/></ZIP>`

Comment: aha. i believe the problem is that im not in root. thus, 'every node in our list' doesnt include the ZIP1.